# Display Profile Image, Can't Select Picture Url

Tags: 2013, javascript, rest, jquery, user-profile

I am attempting to retrieve some profile properties for the current user, and am having a hard time with the profile picture Url specifically.  Version is Sharepoint Foundation 2013.

When I open the Url from the following:

```
requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/SiteUserInfoList/Items(" + userid + ")?$select=Title,Picture";
```

I get the following xml:

```
<id>Web/SiteUserInfoList/Items(userid)</id>
<category term="SP.Data.UserInfoItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
<link rel="edit" href="Web/SiteUserInfoList/Items(userid)" />
<title />
<updated>2016-03-09T17:03:37Z</updated>
<author><name /></author>
<content type="application/xml">
    <m:properties>
      <d:Title>User Full Name</d:Title>
      <d:Picture m:type="SP.FieldUrlValue">
        <d:Description>https:domain/images/username.png</d:Description>
        <d:Url>https:domain/images/username.png</d:Url>
      </d:Picture>
    </m:properties>
    </content>
```

And I'm attempting to use the properties returned in this function:

```
function onSuccess(data, request){
  var fullName = data.d.Title;
  var profilePic = data.d.Picture;
  $(".userName").append(fullName);
  $("#profileImage").attr("src", profilePic);
}
```

I am able to return the Title property no problem, but I had no success getting the picture url.  I was able to work around it with the following changes, but it seems a little open to potential issues:

```
var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/SiteUserInfoList/Items(" + userid + ")/FieldValuesAsText?$select=Title,Picture";

var profilePic = data.d.Picture.split(',')[0];
```

This returned both the Url and Description properties in a string separated by ", " which could be split to give me the value I needed.  Is there a way I can drill down to select the Picture Url property directly, or is this a limitation of Rest?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You use below snippet for getting display name & picture for current logged in user.

```
$.ajax({

    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties",
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
    success: function (data) {
        try {
            profileDisplayName = data.d.DisplayName;
            profilePicture = data.d.PictureUrl;

        } catch (err2) {
            // alert(JSON.stringify(err2));
            console.log(JSON.stringify(err2));
        }
    },
    error: function (jQxhr, errorCode, errorThrown) {
        //alert(errorThrown);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Hope this helps

Sorry my bad , i didn't the sharePoint version. Please ignore

Answer (score 0):

The way I have done it in o365 which I think it is the same SP 2013. results object had the user properties

```
var results = data.d.results;
var image = siteURL + "/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=L&accountname=";
<div class='contact-item'><div class='contact-profile-image'><img src='" + image + results[i].Person.EMail + "'></div>
```